# Are Bugzilla use case questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the [bugzilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bugzilla) tag, I see a lot of questions related to setting up Bugzilla on a server and lots of stuff from the hosting perspective. Is it okay to ask questions relating to using Bugzilla as an end user? (I don't know too much about Bugzilla.)

For example, I was browsing https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/ and was wondering if there was a way to query bugs ordered by number of CCs. Is Stack Overflow a good place to ask this sort of question?

Comment: Very very borderline, and I'd err on the side of *off-topic*. Yes, it's a *software tool commonly used by programmers*, but it is hardly *programming related* in the sense of having anything to do with producing code. Furthermore, it could be an extremely version-specific question, as the Bugzilla developers may rearrange their UI in the next version. That is not *typically* the case with any programming related questions, where deprecation does happen, but at least much more gradually.

Comment: Perhaps https://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Perhaps devops.se?

Comment: @deceze: Counterpoint to UI changes: VS, Eclipse, et al change their UIs more drastically and more frequently than Bugzilla does these days. It's also fair, I think, to point out that Bugzilla is frequently used for things like patch review. Still, it's not as clearly on-topic as one could wish.

Answer (score 5):

Mandatory disclaimer: this is my interpretation, not an official policy.

There are several types of questions you could ask about Bugzilla.

Let's start with the easy ones - questions about programming against Bugzilla (such as "how do I do XYZ with Bugzilla's XMLRPC", or "How can use Bugzilla's Python binding to get information ABC") are just programming questions. They're on-topic just like LinkedIn API or Spotify API are.

The second type of questions I can imagine about Bugzilla are technical questions that aren't about programming, but about administering Bugzilla (such as "I tried to install Bugzilla on CentOS 7 and got this error" or "How can I configure MS Exchange as a mail server for Bugzilla"). While questions about tools for programming are generally on-topic, I feel that Bugzilla isn't really such a tool. While there's a pretty clear consensus about IDEs, Bugzilla isn't really a tool for producing software, it's more of a tool for tracking bugs and managing their statuses. I think such questions wouldn't be appropriate for Stack Overflow, and would be better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) or possibly even [DevOps Beta Stack Exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com).

The third type of questions are about using Bugzilla, be it in the technical level (such as "How can I move a bug to a different component without resetting the assignee?") or the "philosophical" level (such as "Is it OK to close a bug as a duplicate of a different bug that has a completely different scenario but the same root cause?"). These questions too are probably a poor fit for Stack Overflow, and would probably do better on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (formerly known as Programmers.SE).

Your example question ("Is there a way to query bugs ordered by number of CCs?") seems to fall under the third category, so to me it sounds like Software Engineering is the right place for it, but to be honest, I'm not a user of that site, and you may want to consult [their meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) before posting there.